# how do I display text on an image?

Tags: html, css

there is an image in the form of a white rectangle,I want to display text on it,but I can not,and what turns out you can see below in the photo

code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>NAME OF PAGE</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body{
              background: url(back.jpeg) no-repeat;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">


  <div style="text-align:center"><img src="back2.jpg" height=100% width="1300"> 
      <h1>TEXT</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. Check it. Hope it will help you.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>NAME OF PAGE</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body{
              background: url(back.jpeg) no-repeat;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">


  <div style="text-align:center; position: relative; width: 50%; margin: auto;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/J67Ukc8.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"> 
      <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;">TEXT</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1.the image is not in the center but on the left edge

Comment: 2.the text resides from below in the center of the and need from above in the center of the

Comment: @ДОБРЫЙДЕДУШКА now check the answer. I put some edit.

Comment: now the picture in the middle but when you change its width to a value "1300" page stretches to the right and it should be evenly as on my screenshot attached to this question

Comment: just me in the future will need to have on this white rectangle a lot of information and therefore need to expand it

Comment: @ДОБРЫЙДЕДУШКА But if you broaden the width, it can cause horizontal scrolling which is considered as a very bad design in web-UI.

Comment: OK understand you)must)do the latter: I want the text to move by coordinates to make it easier and so I have the maximum in line 3, the words will fit

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Can you tell your requirement in details?

Comment: 3.so the text is moved to the coordinates

Comment: What do you mean by "text is moved to the coordinates"?

Comment: I would like to set the location of the text in this image coordinates and not the fact that you need to enter the top-center or the like.

Comment: Would you ask for the image set to left to right covering the whole image?

Comment: Anywhere on the page but above the image. Right?

Comment: can you give any pictorial value?

Comment: just rewrite the program so that I myself can set the coordinates of the text

Comment: You can do so in the given answer. Just use top, left, bottom, right properties to set the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `position` to solve this issue.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1027/200/300" alt="Snow" style="width:100%; heigth:100%">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry your answer it's not what I need.